# Drawing a Cantor-based fractal set

Tags: fractals, cantor-set

I am trying to draw the following set
$$E=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x+y,x-y\in F\}$$ where $F$ is the middle third Cantor set:
[image]
I think this is what the first iteration looks like:
[image]
but I am really not sure (I'm sorry for the pathetic quality by the way, I was forced to use Paint - I will happily create a nicer image if it is the correct one).

**Could someone tell me if I am correct and if not, what it should llook like please?** Thank you.

Comment: what is middle third in cantor set?

Comment: @SantoshLinkha is the set pictured above, the ones with the lines. Each iteration you remove a middle third of each line segment of the previous iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure on your notation but yes I think so. $E_{0}=[0,1]$, $E_{1}=[0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup[\frac{2}{3},1]$,....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The region bounded by the lines $x+y=0$, $x+y=1$, $x-y=0$ and $x-y=1$ is a diamond (rotated square) with opposite corners at $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$. The zeroth iteration of $E$ is simply that filled-in diamond.

$x+y$ and $x-y$ are perpendicular, so further iterations of $E$ are the intersection of two Cantor sets extended into stripes running across the diamond. Indeed, the first iteration of $E$ should look like this:
[image]
$E$ itself is known as *Cantor dust*, and looks like the below image (rotated of course):
[image]

Comment: That's very nice, thank you. I still don't quite understand why, for example, $(0,1)$ isn't in the set since $x+y=0+1=1\in F$. Could you explain please?

Comment: @JSharpee $x-y=-1$ then, but the Cantor set (at least the canonical one) is only defined over $[0,1]$.

Comment: AHA, it's the AND involved. Thank you very much. I feel silly.